# Make a Div invisible , when moved out of the parent DIV

Tags: jquery, css, html

Please find the code at http://jsfiddle.net/wlogeshwaran/NGL8P/4/

Here i want to make the 'hi' , 'hello' invisible , when it is out of that green box.
What should I do to make them disappear when they are out of the green box.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change it over to div based instead of li based so you can reuse the same css class instead of creating a new style for each one. The updated code can be found by going http://jsfiddle.net/NGL8P/21/

### Javascript

Cleaned up abit since changing html

```
$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".slideHolder").animate({"left": "+=100px"}, "slow");
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".slideHolder").animate({"left": "-=100px"}, "slow");
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  var TotalWidth = 0;
  $('.slides').each(function () {
    TotalWidth = TotalWidth + $(this).width();
  });
  $('.slideHolder').css({width: TotalWidth+"px"});
});​
```

### HTML

```
<button id="left">left</button> <button id="right">right</button>
<div class="webpage">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="slideHolder">    
      <div class="slides">hi</div>
      <div class="slides">hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.block {height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;left:100px;background:green;overflow: hidden;}
.slides {position:relative;float:left;height:100px;width:100px;}
.slideHolder {position:absolute;left:0;}
```

​

Answer (score 3):

You need to add:

```
.block {
    overflow:hidden;
    }

.slide1, .slide2 {
      position:relative;  /* instead of fixed */
}
```

overflow: hidden; will make any element that gets out of the div to not be rendered.

Switching the positions to relative instead of fixed will allow the overflow to take effect. The overflow of different "position scopes" doesn't always work. And this is one of the cases where it doesn't. When hiding with overflow:hidden is always better to have the children with the same kind of position as the parent, to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to this example and tell me if that's what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/NGL8P/16/

Comment: Since the position has become relative , the slides looks uneven .